# How to serialize type information of java.time classes using Jackson-Databind?

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-time, jackson-databind

I am currently working on porting a legacy application from java.util.Date classes to the java.time API. I am using Default Typing to preserve type information.
Because the java.time classes are marked as final, Jackson does not add any type information in the JSON output. This is mostly fine except in this case:

I have a class that has a member of the type Object, which can contain various data types. It is filled at runtime, so I don't know which data type it is going to contain ahead of time. It is then serialized and sent to the client, which deserializes it and checks the datatype using `instanceof`. 
This worked fine with `java.util.Date`, as the type was serialized. `ZonedDateTime`, as there is no type information, gets deserialized to a String, which results in errors in the later code.

I have read the Jackson documentation about the different `DefaultTyping`-Settings, but the option that adds the most type information seems to be `NON_FINAL`, which still results in this problem.

I've also tried to write my own serializer and overwriting the `serializeWithType`-Method, but it is never called.

I could write a non-final wrapper class containing the ZonedDateTime, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Here is my ObjectMapper-Configuration:

```java
ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                    .enable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS)
                    .enable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS)
                    .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID)
                    .disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS)
                    .disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS)
                    .disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS)
                    .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                    .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL)
                    .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                    .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                    .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

This is the result I am getting now:

```
"2019-08-02T16:03:41.988+02:00[Europe/Berlin]"
```

And this is what I'd want:

```
["java.time.ZonedDateTime", "2019-08-02T16:03:41.988+02:00[Europe/Berlin]"]
```

Comment: It’s not my home field, so just asking: Are you using [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)? Would it help if you did?

Comment: I had already included and registered `jackson-datatype-jsr310`. I've now also tried including `jackson-datatype-jdk8`, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer was not applicable in my case, I've implemented a workaround. It's not very elegant and I will remove it if anyone has a better solution, but for the time being it works.

I did it by implementing the following wrapper class using Generic Types:

```
 public class FinalClassContainer <T> {
    private T containedObject;

    public FinalClassContainer(T obj)
    {
        this.containedObject = obj;
    }

    public T getContainedClass()
    {
        return containedObject;
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
[
    "com.test.FinalClassContainer",
    {
        "containedObject": [
            "java.time.ZonedDateTime",
            "2019-08-08T11:22:00.996+02:00[Europe/Berlin]"
        ]
    }
]
```

This allows me to call `container.getContainedClass()` on the client side, which returns the object with the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by providing Jackson with a getter method that produces the desired output.  If you have a getter method for the instance variable, you can tell Jackson to ignore it:

```
public class MyBean
{
    private Object obj;

    // tell jackson to ignore standard getter method
    @JsonIgnore
    public Object getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    // this is the method that jackson will call during serialization
    @JsonProperty("obj")
    public String[] getObjForJson() {
        return new String[] {
            obj.getClass().getName(),
            obj.toString()
        };
    }
}
```

test method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
    myBean.obj = ZonedDateTime.now();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, myBean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
{"obj":["java.time.ZonedDateTime","2019-08-06T11:09:30.467+03:00[Asia/Jerusalem]"]}
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work in my case, as the other objects that can be saved in the member variable may have to be serialized further.

Comment: this answer gives a solution to the question. maybe you need to clarify the complete requirements in the question.